# Both html5 video and flash fallback loading if browser supports both

Tags: flash, html, video

I'm doing Html5 video play on my project with flash fallback (if it doesn't support html5).
But both players are loaded if browser supports both. help me.

```
<video controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="image.url" >
    <source src="video.url" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="video.url" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
</video>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer-3.1.1.swf">
   <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.1.1.swf" />
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
   <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['image.url',
       {'url':'video.url','autoPlay':false}]}" />
   <img alt="Image" src="" width="191px" height="256px" 
       title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
</object>
```

Comment: Ok.  What's the code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place the `<object>` inside the `<video>` tag, making it siblings with the source tags.  If the browser does not support `<video>`, it renders the contents inside, similar to `<noscript>` if scripts were off.

```
<video controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="image.url" >

    <source src="video.url" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="video.url" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>

    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer-3.1.1.swf">
       <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.1.1.swf" />
       <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
       <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
       <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['image.url',{'url':'video.url','autoPlay':false}]}" />
       <img alt="Image" src="" width="191px" height="256px" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>

</video>
```

Comment: But this will make the html5 player as the default player. Is there a way to still use Flash as the first preference and then fallback to html5 if needed?

Comment: @YudongLi the OP asked for "HTML5 video with Flash fallback", not the other way around.